# Should Operations Research have MathJax enabled?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax

A [similar question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29698/will-or-se-have-mathjax) on Area 51 Discussions before we entered private beta. That was closed, so I'm going to ask here.

For those of you who don't know, MathJax is basically a special formatter for mathematical problems/equations and is enabled on several Stack Exchange sites like [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net).

Most or all of the questions asked on OR will probably use math equations of some type, and it would be helpful to have MathJax to format them neater, so I think we should have MathJax enabled as soon as possible.

To take a few examples from https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29698/will-or-se-have-mathjax, here are a few questions operations research-related questions on Mathematics.SE that use MathJax:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217716/kkt-optimisation-condition-of-inequality-constraint-being-zero
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217454/bilinear-objective-function
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215527/infeasible-solution-in-duality-and-dual-simplex-method
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218130/minimizing-univariate-quadratic-via-gradient-descent-choosing-the-step-size
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216198/convergence-rates-of-stochastic-gradient-descent-with-different-sample-size

So, should we have MathJax enabled? If so, when should it be enabled?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, I had already planned on having that set up by time you got here — a bit of a "bonus" for all the delays getting this site set up. I already put in the request.

Watch below which will tell you when…

$$
\Huge MathJax: ACTIVATED
$$

Comment: Thanks, you type quicker than I can tap on my cellphone.

Answer (score 6):

$\gamma$es, MatJax is enabled.

A complete [guide for our site is here](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/51).