# What should the "MathJax help" link (in the LaTeX section of the "Editing Help" page) point to?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax, hyperlinks

According to a Community Manager (in a moderator chat session):

> As you may know, on sites where MathJax is enabled, the `/editing-help` page includes a LaTeX section, with a "MathJax help" link at the bottom of it. By default, this link points to the URL https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/. However, I recently discovered that this URL can be customized for each site that has MathJax enabled.
>
> Right now, only a few sites have actually had this changed (several of them link to a post on their own Meta, though a few link to [Math.SE's MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/414985)). I wanted to reach out to your mod team to see if this is something that would be useful for your community as well. (Ideally, it'd link to a post on your site's Meta tailored to your own community.)

What should this "MathJax help" link point to?

- We already have an FAQ/guide for MathJax stuff here in our Meta: [How do I use MathJax on this site?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site). Should we change the "MathJax help" link to point to that (and maybe include one more answer there pointing to [the Harvard page linked above](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/))?
- Or should this link point to something else instead? (If so, what?)

Feel free to post your recommendations, one per answer. Please upvote the answer(s) you support the most.

Comment: Our Quantum Computing site has also [tag:featured] a [similar request](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/561/278) for their site's FAQ. Thanks for asking this.

Comment: Since this never got escalated to us again after the initial discussion here, I've added the [status-review] tag to it myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that we change the links to our own link at: "[How do I use MathJax on this site?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/51)"

Recently I had a [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62050802#62050802) with the moderator at Quantum Computing and this was my reasoning:

> "User1271772 (& gIS) please note that there's a [huge list](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/index.html) of extensions offered in this answer at OR.SE: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/235/51 - more than a few of which would be useful here. For example: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/braket.html — Rob [14 hours ago](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/523/please-add-chemjax#comment3023_523)".

Each site has MathJax specific needs that are not met by the default URL, and after asking for the URL change once any additional changes can be added to the FAQ by anyone. The default URL could be added to the end of the FAQ, so nothing is lost.

Comment: The "MathJax help" link on OR.SE (and this Meta site) has been changed to point to [this OR Meta post](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site), per your suggestion. Let us know if you encounter any problems!